# Undefined name error in flutter(2.5.3) how to solve

Tags: flutter

I can't define the code I wrote above. This problem has come up many times, but I do not understand the logic.

**final recipes = snapshot.data?.todayRecipes ?? [];** the code is already defined but it looks undefined below

**return TodayRecipeListView(recipes: recipes);** and the error also comes in this part

I would be very grateful if someone could explain the logic of the definition.

```
class ExploreScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final mockService = MockFooderlichService();

  ExploreScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // 2
      future: mockService.getExploreData(),
      // 3
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ExploreData> snapshot) {
        // TODO: Add Nested List Views
        // 4
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          // 5
          final recipes = snapshot.data?.todayRecipes ?? [];
          // TODO: Replace this with TodayRecipeListView
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              child: const Text('Show TodayRecipeListView'),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          // 6

          return TodayRecipeListView(recipes: recipes);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Put in your mind that all things that are future begin without data. So, in your case, at the beginning of the execution it will pass straight to the else and the recipes don't exist.

Comment: another detail is that recipes were defined inside the if block and only there will it be seen.

Comment: What you want to do is very confusing, normally after the data load is finished you show the data, in your case it is showing the text Show TodayRecipeListView

Comment: I got these codes from flutter's recommended book and now it's not working. So how can I get this working?

Comment: Here is the tutorial you are following. Note that the code is different from yours. https://www.raywenderlich.com/books/flutter-apprentice/v2.0/chapters/5-scrollable-widgets#toc-chapter-011-anchor-004

Comment: In item 6 of the tutorial he is putting a progress indicator, which is to show the user that something is being done while the data is being retrieved. In the case of your item 6, you are trying to show the data that was not even recovered.

Comment: Thank you sir i got it and i will fix it